# Обобщенный случай алгоритма Бойера и Мура, для нажождения мажорирующего элемента

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Пытаюсь реализовать обобщенный алгоритма Бойера и Мура. 
Задача : требуется в массиве длиной N найти элементы, встречающийся более N/K раз. 
Вот мой код:

```
vector<int> majorityElement(vector<int> &nums, int k){
    cout <<"in fun\n";
    map<int,int> candidates;
    vector<int> ans;
    for(int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        cout << "here " << i << endl;
        if (candidates.count(nums[i]))
            candidates[nums[i]]++;
        else{
            if (candidates.size() < (k - 1))
                candidates[nums[i]] = 1;
            else{
                for (auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); ++it){
                    candidates[it->first]--;
                    if (candidates[it->first] == 0){
                        candidates.erase(it);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); ++it){
        candidates[it->first] = 0;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.size(); i++){
        if (candidates.count(nums[i]))
            candidates[nums[i]]++;
    }

    for (auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); ++it){
        if (candidates[it->first] > (nums.size() / k))
            ans.push_back(it->first);
    }
    return ans;
```

}

На тесте:
7 3 
1 1 1 2 5 6 7
Программа ломается полностью, при обработке числа 5. 
[Вот тут есть описание алгоритмы с псевдокодом](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При удалении элемента итератор инвалидируется, его больше нельзя использовать (инкрементировать и т.д.). Но метод [erase](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase) возвращает следующий валидный итератор.

Поэтому замените это

```
for (auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end(); ++it) {
    candidates[it->first]--;
    if (candidates[it->first] == 0) {
        candidates.erase(it);
    }
}
```

на это

```
for (auto it = candidates.begin(); it != candidates.end();) {
    if (--(it->second) == 0) {
        it = candidates.erase(it);
    }
    else ++it;
}
```

Также стоит заменить `map` на `unordered_map`

Comment: Большое спасибо!